# Pandas ignore header and a column from json body

Tags: python, json, pandas, selenium

I selected `results` from the json body coming from selenium request. I want to get rid of the header and the first column of the results. Tried some methods from pandas and seems not working for me.

Here is what i tried

```
driver.get('https://reversewhois.domaintools.com/?ajax=mReverseWhois&call=ajaxUpdateRefinePreview&q=%5B%5B%5B%22whois%22%2C%222%22%2C%22VerifiedID%40SG-Mandatory%22%5D%5D%5D')
time.sleep(5)
pre = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("pre").text
data = json.loads(pre)
table = data['results']
tables = pd.read_html(table,header=None)

df = tables[-1]
print(df)
```

I got response like this

```
                    Domain Name Create Date                                        Registrar
0                         001.sg  2019-03-13          WEB COMMERCE COMMUNICATIONS (S) PTE LTD
1                     001cafe.sg  2020-01-01             EXABYTES NETWORK (SINGAPORE) PTE LTD
```

I just want to get rid of the headers and also the first column. I only need domain name and other details. Can someone tell me why my method didint work?

Comment: Does `skiprows` parameter solve the problem ? You can see the details here --> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: Ok it works. but also i need to skip first column.

Comment: You can use `del df['column_name']`

Comment: can i use `del df['']` since first header is blank?? @dzakyputra

Comment: or `df.drop`? what you think?

Comment: I think what you mean by first column is the `index`, as far as I know you can't do anything about that (delete index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Pandas DataFrame* the index is its intrinsic component.
Something like a master key column (usually named *id*) in a relational
database.

So you can not run *del df['']*.

But you can **print** any DataFrame without the index.

One of methods to achieve this is:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

You can also try:

```
df.style.hide_index()
```

Comment: do you have any idea how could i get every index like i want to save it in database?

Comment: It depends on particular API to perform operations on a database.
Some of them contain parameters concerning how to handle the index.
Other solution is to *reset_index*, so that index columns are changed
into "regular" columns and then they can be saved in a database just as other columns.

Answer (score 1):

You must try to use `skiprows` and skip the first row which is the header.

`tables = pd.read_html(table,skiprows=1)`